# Dispatched action not affecting redux store's state

Tags: react-redux, console.log

I am developing an application to manage expenses in React-Redux and at this point the expected behavior is for the different expenses to start to show up in the expenses array inside my console and it is not happening. I still get an empty array.

This is what I have in `app.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AppRouter from './routers/AppRouter';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import { addExpense } from './actions/expenses';
import { setTextFilter } from './actions/filters';
import getVisibleExpenses from './selectors/expenses';
import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';
import './styles/styles.scss';
const store = configureStore();
store.dispatch(addExpense({ description: 'Water bill' }));
console.log(store.getState());
ReactDOM.render(<AppRouter />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

This is my `/actions/expenses` file:

```
import uuid from 'uuid';
// ADD EXPENSE
export const addExpense = ({
  description = '',
  note = '',
  amount = 0,
  createdAt = 0
} = {}) => ({
  type: 'ADD EXPENSE',
  expense: {
    id: uuid(),
    description,
    note,
    amount,
    createdAt
  }
});
// REMOVE EXPENSE
export const removeExpense = ({ id } = {}) => ({
  type: 'REMOVE_EXPENSE',
  id
});
// EDIT EXPENSE
export const editExpense = (id, updates) => ({
  type: 'EDIT_EXPENSE',
  id,
  updates
});
```

This is my `actions/filters` file:

```
// SET TEXT FILTER
export const setTextFilter = (text = '') => ({
  type: 'SET_TEXT_FILTER',
  text
});
// SORT BY DATE
export const sortByDate = () => ({
  type: 'SORT_BY_DATE'
});
// SORT BY AMOUNT
export const sortByAmount = () => ({
  type: 'SORT_BY_AMOUNT'
});
// SET START DATE
export const setStartDate = (startDate) => ({
  type: 'SET_START_DATE',
  startDate
});
// SET END DATE
export const setEndDate = (endDate) => ({
  type: 'SET_END_DATE',
  endDate
});
```

This is my `selectors/expenses` file:

```
export default (expenses, { text, sortBy, startDate, endDate }) => {
  return expenses
    .filter((expense) => {
      const startDateMatch =
        typeof startDate !== 'number' || expense.createdAt >= startDate;
      const endDateMatch =
        typeof endDate !== 'number' || expense.createdAt >= endDate;
      const textMatch = expense.description
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(text.toLowerCase());
      return startDateMatch && endDateMatch && textMatch;
    })
    .sort((a, b) => {
      if (sortBy === 'date') {
        return a.createdAt < b.createdAt ? 1 : -1;
      } else if (sortBy === 'amount') {
        return a.amount < b.amount ? 1 : -1;
      }
    });
};
```

I am not getting any errors in command line, yet I continue to get in console:

```
{expenses: Array(0), filters {...}
expenses []
```

This is my reducer/expenses.js file:

```
const expensesReducerDefaultState = [];

export default (state = expensesReducerDefaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_EXPENSE':
      return [...state, action.expense];
    case 'REMOVE_EXPENSE':
      return state.filter(({ id }) => id !== action.id);
    case 'EDIT_EXPENSE':
      return state.map((expense) => {
        if (expense.id === action.id) {
          return {
            ...expense,
            ...action.updates
          };
        } else {
          return expense;
        }
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and this is my reducers/filters.js file:

```
const filtersReducerDefaultState = {
  text: '',
  sortBy: 'date',
  startDate: undefined,
  endDate: undefined
};

export default (state = filtersReducerDefaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_TEXT_FILTER':
      return {
        ...state,
        text: action.text
      };
    case 'SORT_BY_AMOUNT':
      return {
        ...state,
        sortBy: 'amount'
      };
    case 'SORT_BY_DATE':
      return {
        ...state,
        sortBy: 'date'
      };
    case 'SET_START_DATE':
      return {
        ...state,
        startDate: action.startDate
      };
    case 'SET_END_DATE':
      return {
        ...state,
        endDate: action.endDate
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs (https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store#dispatch-action), `store.dispatch` is synchronous, and so is your `addExpense` function.

Therefore, the problem must be in the reducer that handles the action. Either you do not have a reducer that handles this action, probably resulting in the default behaviour, which is to return the original state (this depends on your reducer code), or an error occurs in your reducer that stops this action from making any changes.

Both of these situations are unlikely to result in an exception being thrown (again, depending on your reducer code).

**EDIT**

In your `/actions/expenses` file you set the action type to `ADD EXPENSE`, but in the reducer your `switch` looks for `ADD_EXPENSE`! So, either add an underscore in the `/actions/expenses` file or remove it from the reducer.

There would have been no console error because your code treats it as a default case.

In future, I would recommend console logging the `action.type` in the default case of the `switch` to make sure you are not missing any actions. Also, you should use an enum for the action types, not just a string, so that it is a lot harder to make this same mistake. See the example below:

Reducer:

```
import actionType from "../actionsEnum";

const expensesReducerDefaultState = [];

export default (state = expensesReducerDefaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionType.ADD_EXPENSE:
      return [...state, action.expense];
    // ...
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Enum File:

```
const actionType = {
    ADD_EXPENSE: "ADD_EXPENSE"
};

// Prevent new actions from being added or deleted outside this file
export default Object.freeze(actionType);
```

Comment: I added the code from my two reducers file. Could you take a look and confirm?